# Can Vim display two spaces for indentation, while keeping four spaces in the file?

Tags: vim, indentation

I want to work on someone else's project, and he uses 4 spaces for indentation. I use 2, and my screen is not big enough to edit using 4 spaces comfortably.

Can I configure Vim to display 2 spaces for indentation, but write 4 to the file?

Answer (score 8):

<sup>This is the opposite of what was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514336/gvim-show-4-spaces-but-save-2-spaces-tabs).</sup>

Yes, you can! If you have the "conceal" option, you can try this out.

```
:syntax match spaces /  / conceal cchar= "Don't forget the space after cchar!
:set concealcursor=nvi
:set conceallevel=1
```

Here are what these commands do:

- Set the replacement character for 2 spaces to 1 space
- Keep text under cursor concealed for normal, visual, and insert modes
- Enable concealing text with one character

You still have to set your `tabstop`, `softtabstop` and `shiftwidth` to `4`, but it *looks* and *feels* like it is `2`! However, when you write the file, it's really `4`.

If you want to turn concealment off you can do one of two things:

1. Remove conceal rule `:syntax clear spaces` or
2. Allow concealed text to be expanded under the cursor `:set concealcursor=`

Comment: Is there a way to the opposite? Set 2 spaces to appear like 4 spaces?

Comment: @Uri See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514336/gvim-show-4-spaces-but-save-2-spaces-tabs. Note, I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 4):

The help has an example for a similar use case of different tab widths, see `:help retab-example`.

Adapting that to halving / doubling spaces:

```
:autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost  * %substitute/^\( \+\)\1/\1/e
:autocmd BufWritePre               * %substitute/^ \+/&&/e
```

Comment: That's great! Does it run on all files, or only the current one?

Comment: With `*`, on all. See `:help autocmd-patterns` on how to influence that.

Answer (score 0):

If he uses true spaces instead of tabs (which it sounds like), no, you cannot have vim display 2 spaces where there are 4.  However, you can tell vim the following commands to replace all 4-space groups with the tab character, and then display them as 2 spaces.

```
:set tabstop=4 ! display a tab as 4 columns
:set shiftwidth=4
:set noexpandtab
:gg=G   ! convert the whole file to tabs
:set tabstop=2 !display a tab as 2 columns
:set shiftwidth=2
```

When you are ready to submit your work,

```
:set tabstop=4
:set shiftwidth=4
:set expandtab
:%retab
```

Should convert it back.