# (g)Vim -> show 4 spaces, but save 2 spaces (tabs)

Tags: vim, spaces

Is it possible to open files that are indented with 2 spaces, but show me 4 space indentation, and when I make 4 spaces, it saves in a 2 space format?

**Edit**

It turns out I also need to be able to ensure that it works if the file has a mix of tabs, 2 spaces, and 4 spaces.

**Edit 2**

So, here is my current solution.  I'm having to remap my  (originally mapped to :w) so that I can place my cursor back where it was (and give me one "history back" as far as cursor positions when I do a save.  Is there a way to do this without affecting cursor position (and not adding the substitution to the history, either)?

```
function! s:ShimSpaces()
    nunmap <C-S>
    nmap <C-S> ms``mt:w<Cr>`t`s
    augroup SeoTabs
        autocmd!
        autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost * set tabstop=4
        autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost * %substitute/^ \+/&&/e
        autocmd BufReadPost              * %substitute/ \+$//e
        autocmd BufWritePre              * %substitute/^\( \+\)\1/\1/e
        autocmd BufWritePre              * set tabstop=2
        autocmd BufWritePre              * retab
    augroup END
endfunction
command! -n=0 -bar ShimSpaces :call s:ShimSpaces()
```

Comment: I hope this is a possible solution for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217058/vim-reformat-a-python-file-to-have-4-space-indentations

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, Sudip.  Not quite.  I'm thinking that Ingo may have the right idea below. (Just need to try it out.)  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>This is the opposite of what was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849368/can-vim-display-two-spaces-for-indentation-while-keeping-four-spaces-in-the-fil).</sup>

The help has an example for a similar use case of different tab widths, see `:help retab-example`.

Adapting that to doubling / halving spaces:

```
:augroup AdaptIndent
    :autocmd!
    :autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost  * %substitute/^ \+/&&/e
    :autocmd BufWritePre               * %substitute/^\( \+\)\1/\1/e
:augroup END
```

With `*`, this will affect *all* opened files. To restrict this to certain files, see `:help autocmd-patterns`.

Edit: With the `:augroup` wrapping, this can be turned off again via `:autocmd! AdaptIndent`. This way, you can easily toggle this on / off. For ease of use, I'd put this in a function and define a custom command calling it.

Comment: I *love* this idea.  I have yet to try it out, but I'll let you know.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually - one question.  How would I make it so that I can turn this on or off during a session?

Comment: Here's another question:  How could I do it if I'm unsure if others who have worked on it mixed tabs, 2 spaces, and 4 spaces?

Comment: For all (current and future) files?! I've added instructions to the answer.

Comment: So, what you have there should work regardless of mixture of tabs/spaces?

Comment: You asked for spaces, you got spaces. Tabs make this more complex, but solvable. Have a look at `:retab`.